# Dask object memory size larger than the file size?

Tags: python, csv, bigdata, dask

I have a csv file that is 15Gb in size according to `du -sh filename.txt`. However, when I load the file to dask, the dask array is almost 4 times larger at 55Gb. Is this normal? Here is how I am loading the file.

```
cluster = LocalCluster()  # Launches a scheduler and workers locally
client = Client(cluster)  # Connect to distributed cluster and override default@delayed
input_file_name = 'filename.txt'

@delayed
def load_file(fname, dtypes=dtypes):
    ddf = dd.read_csv(input_file_name, sep='\t', dtype=dtypes) #dytpes is dict of {colnames:bool}
    arr = ddf.to_dask_array(lengths=True)
    return arr
result = load_file(input_file_name)

arr = result.compute()
arr
```

|  | Array | Chunk |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bytes | 54.58 GiB | 245.18 MiB |
| Shape | (1787307, 4099) | (7840, 4099) |
| Count | 456 Tasks | 228 Chunks |
| Type | object | numpy.ndarray |

I wasn't expecting the dask array to be so much larger than the input file size.

The file is contains binary values, so I tried passing bool dtype to see if it will shrink in size but I see no difference.

Comment: this seems pretty normal to me. There is no reason that an object in memory should have a similar memory footprint as a text file on disk (unless you are simply reading it as text/bytes).

Comment: So, just consider a simple example. suppose I `json.load` a file, and the file simply contains `{"abc": 999}`. That requires 12 bytes on disk represented as text. Deserialized in Python, it is over 232 bytes in memory (about 300, actually, 232 bytes for the dict itself, 52 bytes for the `str`, plust 28 bytes for the int).

Comment: Of course, dask is using much less bloated ways of storing objects in memory compared to vanilla python objects, but the point remains

Comment: To elaborate, consider a `np.ndarray` of `np.float64` dtype, and the text stores a bunch of numbers like this: `0.12321323242424242` and the *average* length of the decimal numbers is 16 digits... well, when stored in an array that would require *half* the size in memory than on disk, since each of those floats will be stored in 8 bytes. Now, consider instead we use a `np.int64` array to store a bunch of numbers in the range of 0-1000. The average length is well below 4, so the object in memory would require *twice as much* as the text on disk, the opposite of the previous example.

Comment: in any case, the point is, these sorts of discrepancies are normal

Comment: That being said, for such a large array, if dtype is really bool (which we cannot know here), it should have been smaller. A numpy array of bools takes approx 1 byte per bool

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. This was helpful. The dtype really is bool and I passed that as an argument. There must be other overheads that are causing the size to balloon. I expected the size to be larger, just not 4x larger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer- it was right there on the output of arr where it says the Type -> 'object'. Looks like converting from dask dataframe to array using `arr = ddf.to_dask_array(lengths=True)` does not preserve the bool object type. I was able to reduce the memory load significantly by explicitly casting it as bool type again.

```
# load the dask dataframe and convert to array
@delayed
def load_to_arr(fname, dt):
    ddf = dd.read_csv(fname, sep='\t', dtype=dt)
    arr = unitig_ddf.to_dask_array(lengths=True)
    arr = unitig_arr.astype(bool, copy=False) # recast as bool array
    return unitig_arr
result = load_to_arr(input_file_name, dt=dtypes)
arr = result.compute()
arr
```

This now gives an object that is of type `bool` as size 6Gb, which is more reasonable.

|  | Array | Chunk |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bytes | 6.82 GiB | 30.65 MiB |
| Shape | (1787307, 4099) | (7840, 4099) |
| Count | 456 Tasks | 228 Chunks |
| Type | bool | numpy.ndarray |